# refactor the big lists

Tags: c#, refactoring

I HAVE About twenty lists in a class like below

```
public class Storepart : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> A;

    public List<GameObject> B;
}
```

and I need to save a special index in each one, is there a way to refactor it?

```
public savedata() {

    for (int i = 0; i < Storepart.A.Count; i++) {
        if (Storepart.A[i].activeSelf) {
            SaveAindex = i;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Storepart.B.Count; i++) {
        if (Storepart.B[i].activeSelf) {
            SaveBindex = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a simple `LINQ` aproach here.

```
using System.Linq;

SaveAindex = Storepart.A.IndexOf(Storepart.A.LastOrDefault(gameObject => gameObject.activeSelf));
```

This expression consists of 2 parts. The inner call to `LastOrDefault` traverses your List and returns the last element where the `activeSelf` is true. The outer call gets the index of the element found by `LastOrDefault`.

Remarks:

- If you are looking for the first element in your `List<GameObject` where `activeSelf?` is true use `FirstOrDefault`
- The result of this LINQ expresion will be 0 if no element is found.